# What are some good tactics for getting the "outmatched" achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

What are some good tactics, race and map choices for getting the outmatched achievements? I'm mainly talking about those against 3 or more hard/very hard AI's, since beating such a large force seems almost impossible. I think that a good race and map choice could do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every outmatched achievement, I did the exact same thing:

1. Only do the Insane matches (The VHard Hard and Medium Achievements come along with the Insane one)
2. Play on Megatron, it offers a great base that you can hit every enemy from one central position, which leads me to..
3. Play Protos v Terran. Do a standard Cannon Rush:
   Rush one of your initial probes to the center of their 4 base area.

   Build a few probes while the rusher is in transit. As soon as he his his location you should have enough minerals to build your first pylon.

   The key is to build it far enough from all bases to not bee seen when placing. It cannot be seen when its initially placed, or they will send SCV's at you. If they see it while its building, thats no big deal. They just can't see the initial warp.
4. Wait for the Pylon to complete, then throw down a forge. Wait for the forge, then start placing Photon Cannons at the perimeter of your lone pylon's power range.
5. Rinse and repeat. Just keep placing cannons and pylons to expand as needed. Eventually they will quit as you've damaged their game too much.

**Warnings**

If you don't damage them enough with the initial few cannons, they will ramp into Mech and you will lose.

If they see you place the forge or the pylon, they will mass attack with SCV's and you lose.

Follow those steps and you will be on your way to **Outmatched Crusher**

Comment: has anyone tried this lately?  I don't know if the AI was patched or I just suck, but I cannot get the cannon rush to work, on insane or very hard.  even if i do get a cannon up before they notice me, they flood me with marines which overwhelm the cannon.

Comment: I can try this tonight, but you should have cannon's active before they have enough marines active to shut you down.

Answer (score 4):

Cannon rushing on Megaton still works, but you need to make a few changes for the upgraded AI in patch 1.2.  I recommend PvT and you must start your cannons below their ramp, or they swarm you with probes.

Here's a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLRT3Pakqvc) laying it all out.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking into the same tactics as the one for getting the orlan achievement:

[Are there any handy tricks for ousting insane AI opponents?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/any-handy-tricks-for-ousting-insane-ai-opponents/5592#5592)

go turtle somewhere safe, like a map with islands. you can the pick them off one by one with carriers?

Comment: Just a note - for outmatched vs 4x Insane AI this seems not possible. I have tried like 5 times to turtle on islands and i'm sooner or later overrun with such a large force that nothing can save me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still possible in SC2 because I'm still working through the campaign*, but in SC1 there were a lot of micro maps where it was possible to beat the hardest AI 7v1 with any of the races (although Zerg was VERY tough because they couldn't turtle before the first rushes due to having to wait for creep to spread.

The strategy was to just turtle, then either build an overwhelming air force, or in the case of Terrans build siege tanks to wipe out your immediate neighbors and then just expand from there. Once you had a second base you could build out unit producing structures and eventually wipe out the AIs one at a time.

It was often hit or miss though - sometimes as Protoss a Terran AI would get siege tanks and it would be impossible to hold them off long enough to get a counter. As Terrans you might get hit by stealth units that could hit your blockading supply depots from out of range of your turrets, or you might face siege tanks or mutalisks that could overwhelm you.

*hey, I work and have a family, what can I do :)