# Any tips for the Insane AI co-op matches with AI allies?

Tags: starcraft-2

This [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/any-handy-tricks-for-ousting-insane-ai-opponents) has several good tips for how to get the Insane FFA achievement. I tried one of the strategies and it worked well.

However I'm trying to do the ones where you have to have Insane AI allies (3v3, 4v4) and for some reason my allies do nothing. I've tried 4-5 matches and it pretty much goes down the same way each time. My allies build up a decent force very quickly (no defense at all though), and they don't do any thing. The computer will then team up one on of them, by the time reinforcements get there the ally is already destroyed.

I thought maybe my allies were just waiting for me to initiate an attack, but when I tried that it didn't go so well. They stayed at the bases and my entire force was lost.

Any tips to make this easier? Or should I just stick with the FFA tactic and go hide on an island and build up an Battlecruiser army. (Of course, then it becomes 1v3 or 1v4 since my allies will all be dead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 'Kin' achievements i had a hard time until i ended up using silly tactics for each of the 3 races to allow my team the win with a lot more ease, and a lot less frustration at my idiotic teammates.

---

**Protos**

Cannon Rush. You can see my description of it [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/tactics-for-getting-the-outmatched-achievements-in-starcraft-2/5942#5942).

The basic gist is: send a starting probe to their base (on Megatron) and set up a pylon and forge, then start planting cannons until they are all hampered enough that your team rolls over them.

---

**Zerg**

Spine Crawler Rush.

This works best on maps where all the bases are seperated.

This means your opponents all need to be zerg.

Harvest for < 1min with all of your drones. Build 1 or 2 new drones. Then save up for a pool. After the min has past send 2-4 of your drones into the opponents base. Then split them up 2 per opponent base. As soon as you have the resources turn those drones into spine crawlers behind their resource line. Use the minerals to funnel the drones so only one can attack your spine at a time.

If all goes well you will land 2 crawlers behind 2 different bases and it will cause enough economic damage that the other 3 players on your team will be able to roll over the opposing AI. If all does not go well, they will have attacked your crawlers and killed them. Save yourself the time and pack up and surrender. Just try it again.

---

**Terran**

I chose Protoss for my opponents on this one.

This works best on maps where there are two players per base.

I built fast into 3 barracks with tech labs and mass produced Reapers.

I then proceed to reaper harass the opponents, watching for striders and zealots to come defend while cleaning house of probes. If you are able to take out a nexus early, that's always very helpful.

If all goes well you did enough damage that your buddies can clean house, otherwise start over.

---

Hope this helps out, this is exactly how I did them.

Comment: These strategies worked great. Except for Terran, I found it easier to just bunker rush them.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to attack with an air unit at the computers base.  All computers will pull its troops from attacking and go after that air unit.  Before the air unit gets attacked just fly out of range.  You just go back and forth taunting the computers base like this.  Eventually you will have built up a force to deal with the computers without really ever being attacked.